# Use dialofRef to pass config between components in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using `angular-material` in `Angular 4` and I want after setting the config (`data, id`) in my first component to pass it to another component so that I can read the properties.

In my (`news-feed.component.ts`) I have this function:

```
editPost(id,item) {
    const config = new MatDialogConfig();
    config.id = id;
    config.data = item;
    const dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PostComponent> = this.dialog.open(PostComponent, config);
    dialogRef.componentInstance.editedPost(config);
}
```

And in my (`post.component.ts`):

```
editedPost(config) {
    console.log(config.data);
}
```

And this is what I got in my console:
[image]

My data is (das) word, that's mean it can read property 'data', and when I press any key the error repeated itself in console. What I've missed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative solution by using `dialogRef`.

In (`news-feed.component.ts`):

```
editPost(id,item) {
        const dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PostComponent> = this.dialog.open(PostComponent);
        dialogRef.componentInstance.myPost = item;
        dialogRef.componentInstance.myId = id;
    }
```

And in my (`post.component.ts`):

```
public myPost: any;
public myId: any;

editedPost() {
        console.log(this.myPost);
        console.log(this.myId);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: @Kpfromer Dear Kpfromer, I know that but I can't mark my answer until tomorrow. Best Regards